# Error while using load_table_from_dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load data from MYSQL to BigQuery. I'm using pandas,jaydebeapi and load_table_from_dataframe.
While using the same, getting below error:

```
>>> job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(chunk, table_id)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aarpan_roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 1993, in load_table_from_dataframe
    parquet_compression=parquet_compression,
  File "/home/aarpan_roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 486, in dataframe_to_parquet
    arrow_table = dataframe_to_arrow(dataframe, bq_schema)
  File "/home/aarpan_roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 450, in dataframe_to_arrow
    bq_to_arrow_array(get_column_or_index(dataframe, bq_field.name), bq_field)
  File "/home/aarpan_roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 224, in bq_to_arrow_array
    return pyarrow.Array.from_pandas(series, type=arrow_type)
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 755, in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 265, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 80, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
TypeError: an integer is required
>>>
```

Couple of points:

1. My source table exists and has below schema:

   ```
   EMPID INTEGER, 
   EMPNAME VARCHAR, 
   STREETADRESS VARCHAR, 
   REGION VARCHAR, 
   STATE VARCHAR, 
   COUNTRY VARCHAR, 
   joining_date date, 
   last_update_date TIMESTAMP(6) -- to hold till millisecond
   ```
2. My target table also exists in BigQuery and below is the schema:

   ```
   create table if not exists `Project.dataset.table_name`
   (EMPID INT64,
   EMPNAME STRING,
   STREETADRESS STRING,
   REGION STRING,
   STATE STRING,
   COUNTRY STRING,
   joining_date DATE,
   last_update_date TIMESTAMP
   );
   ```
3. Below is the code I'm using:

   ```
   import datetime
   from google.cloud import bigquery
   import pandas as pd
   import jaydebeapi
   import os

   client = bigquery.Client()

   table_id = "<project_id>.<dataset>.<target_table>"
   database_host='<IP Address>'
   database_user='<user id>'
   database_password='<password>'
   database_port='<port>'
   database_db='<database_name>'

   jclassname = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url = "jdbc:mysql://{host}:{port}/{database}".format(host=database_host, port=database_port, database=database_db)
         driver_args = [database_user, database_password]
         jars = ["/<Home_Dir>/script/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar"]
         libs = None

   cnx = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars=jars, libs=libs)
   query='select EMPID,EMPNAME,STREETADRESS,REGION,STATE,COUNTRY,joining_date,last_update_date from <table_name>'

   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   for chunk in pd.read_sql(query, cnx, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, columns=None,chunksize=500000):chunk.apply(lambda x: x.replace(u'\r', u' ').replace(u'\n', u' ') if isinstance(x, str) or isinstance(x, unicode) else x)

   job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(chunk, table_id)
   job.result()
   ```

Kindly help me getting the issue resolved. I tried to use LoadJobConfig as well, but same error is coming.

Comment: Fix the indent and statements in the `for chunk in pd.read_sql(...)` block.

Comment: It would be helpful if you printed the schema of the resulting pandas chunks.  The error seems to indicate some sort of schema mismatch.  Also what version of Arrow and BQ client are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm running this from python prompt. The prompt output is below:

>>> 
    EMPID    EMPNAME                           STREETADRESS  REGION        STATE COUNTRY joining_date     last_update_date
0  168050  Arpan Roy  A 3/3 Anandanagar;Dakshin Behala Road  Behala  West Bengal   India   2005-11-17  2020-08-23 08:57:30

==========PyArrow ==========
numpy>=1.14 
enum34>=1.1.6
six>=1.0.0

How can I check BQ Client Version?

Comment: Hi All, I found the issue. For DATE and TIMESTAMP columns we need to use parse_dates=['joining_date','last_update_date'] in pd.read_sql:
targettabledttscols=['joining_date','last_update_date']
for chunk in pd.read_sql(query, cnx, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=targettabledttscols, columns=None,chunksize=500000):chunk.apply(lambda x: x.replace(u'\r', u' ').replace(u'\n', u' ') if isinstance(x, str) or isinstance(x, unicode) else x)

Now I need to figure why millisecond is not captured in the "chunk" in pd.read_sql. Anyone faced the similar issue and got any resolution? Help pls

Answer (score 0):

Is that the same code you copied? i mean what about the indents statements?

```
for chunk in pd.read_sql(query, cnx, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, columns=None,chunksize=500000):
    chunk.apply(lambda x: x.replace(u'\r', u' ').replace(u'\n', u' ') if isinstance(x, str) or isinstance(x, unicode) else x)
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(chunk, table_id)
    job.result()
```

Fix the above line.

Comment: Hi, I'm running it from Python Prompt and hence indentation is like that. I'm getting proper output from the dataframe. The indentation you mentioned, is there is actual python code.

>>> 
    EMPID    EMPNAME                           STREETADRESS  REGION        STATE COUNTRY joining_date     last_update_date
0  168050  Arpan Roy  A 3/3 Anandanagar;Dakshin Behala Road  Behala  West Bengal   India   2005-11-17  2020-08-23 08:57:30